# Why are conscience and science pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Conscience has a /ʃ/ sound in the middle of the word.

Science has a /saɪ/ sound, not a /ʃ/ sound.

What rule makes conscience have the /ʃ/ sound and what rule makes science have the /saɪ/ sound?

They are spelled very similarly.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because they're different words.  They do supposedly derive from the same root, but they separated in late Latin, then hopped to French, before being adapted into English.

Comment: Sound differently? Are you using sound as a verb? Otherwise it sounds rather different to standard grammar.

Answer (score 3):

The reason boils down to English [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) patterns.

*Science* is stressed on its first syllable and the vowel/diphthong in stressed syllable is strong so it's pronounced **/ˈsaɪ.əns/**.

Another example is *scintillating* which is stressed on the first syllable so it's pronounced **/ˈsɪntɪleɪtɪŋ/**.

On the other hand, the monosyllabic prefix ***con-*** bears the primary word stress so when it's added to the word *science*, the primary stress from the word *science* moves to the prefix *con-* therefore *conscience* is stressed on the first syllable and is pronounced **/ˈkɒnʃ(ə)ns/** not /ˈkɒn.saɪ.əns/ (the vowel in unstressed syllable often reduces).

The /ʃ/ sound is due to *[Yod-coalescence](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yod-coalescence)*.

Other examples are:

- Extension -> **/ɛkˈstɛnʃ(ə)n/**.
- Social -> **/ˈsəʊʃ(ə)l/**.